# Confusing increment behaviour

Tags: c, arduino

```
int i = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(i == 1){
      Serial.print(i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

This is intended to only print the value of `i` once. Why does it keep printing 1 forever?

This code works properly only writing `i` once:

```
int i = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if(i == 1){
      Serial.print(i);
    }
    i = 2;
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole program? Who calls loop?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick This is an arduino sketch so I guess `loop` in called in the arduino library that gets linked at compile time.

Comment: not sure, but try to add `volatile` to `int i`, maybe it some optimization-kind problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `loop()` is called in a loop:

- `i` will overflow in the first example.
- In the second example it is fixed to the value of `2` after the first iteration.

Comment: Of course, if I add another Serial.print(i) outside the conditional I see it going all the way up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to add some delay because sometimes you can miss the first `Serial.println();`.

Something like that:

```
int i = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000); //wait for one second
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your first example to work longer. Change "int" to "long".

int can only store 2 bytes. -32,768 to 32,767. You will reach this number really fast.
long can store 4 bytes. -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. This will take a whiiiile.